# How to remove trailing zeros after decimal points from number column in sqlplus?

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have a one database table field called Amount which type is number(38,8), and in sqlplus I have formatted the column like "COLUMN Amount FORMAT 999999999999999999999999.99999",but while writing into csv we are getting always trialing zeros.
e.g if number is 9.23 then result is will be 9.2300

e.g if number is 9 then result is will be 9.0000

How to remove trailing zeros.

Please help me..

Comment: why cant you cast them as `varchar` columns

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `to_char` and the format-code `TM` (see [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00210))

```
SELECT to_char(column, 'TM') FROM table;
```

examples:

```
SELECT to_char(9.2300, 'TM') FROM dual; -- returns 9.23
SELECT to_char(9.0000, 'TM') FROM dual; -- returns 9
SELECT to_char(100, 'TM') FROM dual;    -- returns 100
SELECT to_char(010, 'TM') FROM dual;    -- returns 10
```

edit:

With

```
SELECT round(to_char(column, 'TM'), 5) FROM table;
```

you can limit your result to 5 decimal places.

```
SELECT to_char(round(123.654321000, 5), 'TM') FROM dual; -- returns 123.65432
```

Comment: This doesn't restrict the output to 5 decimal places. But OP could do e.g. `to_char(round(9.23001, 5), 'TM')`

Comment: @kfinity Thank you, it works! I did not recognize this as a obligatory requirement.

Answer (score 0):

TO_NUMBER function also removes the zeroes after decimal point.

eg : 1.4500 to 1.45, 1.9000 to 1.9 etc.

Sample Query :

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER(column_name) FROM table_name;
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
select rtrim(rtrim(to_char(column_name), 0 ), '.' ) from table_name;
```